# How can I first download KDE files and then install them offline on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg, aptitude

How can I first download **KDE** files and then install them offline on Ubuntu?

Comment: if an answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install -d kde`. To install: `sudo apt-get install kde`.

If you meant Kubuntu instead of KDE (they're similar but slightly different, and Kubuntu includes KDE): `sudo apt-get install -d kubuntu-desktop`, `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` to install.

To get the full array of Kubuntu default programs: `sudo apt-get install -d kubuntu-full`, `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-full` to install.

Basically, any package that you want to download but not install, pass the `-d` flag to `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean or not, but if I understand you correctly, you want to download some KDE packages and install them offline later. In that case, you can use

```
apt-get download package_name(s)
```

or

```
aptitude download package_name(s)
```

This will download the required package(s) to the current directory. You can later install the package(s) with

```
dpkg -i /path/to/package(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

as the quite popular answer at askubuntu says: https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

**Keryx** could be your choice. Just not sure if it's still actively developed. (see the reffered answer for more info)